# Pure HTML Music Player

Tags: html, mp3, audio-player

How can I use pure HTML to make a browser-integrated flash-free online music player? Like, you click on a button, and the music starts playing. I have tried everything with `<embed>` and with(out) `<noembed>`, but none of it seems to work. I need it to work in Firefox.

I have an MP3 file.

EDIT: Actually, folks, I am SO sorry for asking this question. I have now seen that I simply had not written the path correctly. It all works quite fine with the `<embed src="../../path/to/file.mp3" autostart="false" width="20" height="20"/>` tag.
The thing is, I was trying to write it for browsers that don't support Flash, like e. g. iPad's Safari.

Comment: Create an image element then preload all the next images with javascript, start to play it by changing the src attribute every 33 ms, oh wait, u want html5? Use <video>

Comment: -1 @M28: What does the `<video>` tag and image preloading etc. have to do with *music*?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused :P, well, most musics have clips so... ._.

Comment: well, actually, I don't have any video. it's an MP3 file. pure. by the way: it should not be very big... :P

Comment: Actually, folks, I am SO sorry for asking this question. I have now seen that I simply had not written the path correctly. It all works quite fine with the <embed src="../../path/to/file.mp3" autostart="false" width="20" height="20"/> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is not an answer to the question per se, I am adding it for completeness.

[This link](http://www.danfergusdesign.com/classfiles/generalReference/objectTag.html) has every possible permutation you can imagine...

I am not sure if the part below will work in FireFox:

Here is how to embed Windows Media Player into your HTML.

To embed an object in HTML document, the object class ID is required. The class ID for Windows Media Player 7, 9, 10 and 11 is clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6.

Insert the following code into your HTML document to embed Windows Media Player 7 and later:

```
<OBJECT id="VIDEO" width="320" height="240" 
    style="position:absolute; left:0;top:0;"
    CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
    type="application/x-oleobject">

    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="your file or url">
    <PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">
    <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True">
    <PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
    <PARAM name="PlayCount" value="9999">
</OBJECT>
```

In the URL parameter, you can specify a URL (for streaming) or a local file.

Comment: -1 This is an ActiveX solution, which is like a non-standard, non-free, non-portable version of Flash.

Comment: This was proposed for the sake of having a complete answer - I know it is not an HTML answer.

Comment: don't worry. you have found so much, I will just choose this as the answer.

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2010/01/html-5-audio-player-demo.html) ought to help. The HTML5 audio tag has decent support with newer versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera (sadly no Internet Explorer).
You may need to convert your .mp3 to .ogg or another format because certain browsers only allow certain formats.

Oh, you'll need Javascript for controls like .play(), .pause()...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible yet (comes with HTML5).
You could use the [Yahoo Media Player](http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/) which works with Javascript.

Comment: Wow, that is impressive, but unfortunately requires flash.

Comment: I don't think it uses Flash but pure Javascript. I might be wrong - where did you find some?